# hide a class when in other class not compare a class name called "column"

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

I have 2 `div` with respective sub class , now I want when in first class not  compare a sub class called "column" hide another class out called "hidecontent"

```
<div class="primary">

<div class="column">column content</div>

</div>


<div class="hidecontent">

</div>
```

`jQuery`:

```
<script>
$(".primary").ready(function() {
       if($(this).hasClass("column"))  {  }


else  { $(".hidecontent").css("display", "none");   }

                                }
                    )};
</script>
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `.hasClass()` on child elements of `.primary` which checks a class name on the selector, you have to check if `.primary` is actually containing `.column`:

You can try this:

```
$(".hidecontent").css("display", function(){
    return $('.primary').children().hasClass('column') ? "block" : "none" ;
});
```

A test is below:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".hidecontent").css("display", function() {
    return $('.primary').children().hasClass('column') ? "block" : "none";
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="primary">
primary
  <div class="column">column content</div>

</div>


<div class="hidecontent">
  should be hidden if column is not found in the primary.
</div>
```

---

Although you can make use of `.toggle()` too:

```
$(".hidecontent").toggle($('.primary').children().hasClass('column'))
```

or

```
$(".hidecontent").toggle($('.primary > *').hasClass('column'))
```

Comment: but this work when compare a text content "column " not when the class is called column, how make this ?

Comment: id does not look for text content. `.has()` method returns a boolean value if `.primary` has a child with a specific class `.column`.

Comment: You can test it like this `alert($('.primary').has('.column'));` will surely alert in true because that satisfies that condition.

Comment: yes i have your same idea , but if you try to insert your snippet on jsfiddle example ,and change the colums class name with other continue to show hidecontent

Comment: @SURTLER77 so you are saying that you have multiple instances of `.primary` some of them have `.column` and some does not. right.

Comment: i teste only your code on jsfiddle , without never add code. https://jsfiddle.net/3g8325dL/ , uou can show the class colums now is column8888 but continue to show hidecontent

Comment: Explain more about your issue? Now i am not able to understand. The way you have written your js code and markup this is what can be done. Can you post your fiddle link?

Comment: i have send a jsfiddle, the problem start from your snippet never code i have added

Comment: @SURTLER77 check the updated code and this is the updated fiddle for you: https://jsfiddle.net/3g8325dL/1/

Answer (score 1):

`$(this)` is the current object which is `div.primary`, not `div.column`. You can try to check if the element is present. -

```
if($(this).find(".column").length > 0)  {
```

Comment: not understand , can you send a full code example ? thanks